# Installing Mercurial on Redhat Linux

Tags: linux, mercurial, installation, redhat

Will Mercurial work on Redhat Linux? I tried, yum install mercurial, with no success. I tried downloading a tar ball from Mercurial site but it failed when I tried to install. Does Mercurial work at all on Redhat?

Comment: I'd suggest moving this to the Unix StackExchange.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download#Linux_.28.rpm.29)'s instructions for obtaining RPM packages for Linux systems.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/582bceb8a605f760) is a discussion describing many methods for obtaining Mercurial in Red Hat.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the link to the Red Hat RPMs! I was really having a hard time finding an older version that one of my engineers was requesting.

Comment: The `rpm -i http://pkgs.repoforge.org/mercurial/mercurial-2.2.2-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm` just saved my day :-) (1.4 was so old that I had some unsupported dotencode problems.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Mercurial wiki [has instructions](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download) on adding their yum repo. I don't see any recent (3.x) mercurial versions in the answer's link above.

Answer (score 1):

On Rhel 7.2 i performed below command and it worked like charm :)

```
sudo rpm -ivh https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/centos7/RPMS/x86_64/mercurial-3.4-0.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial project [provides RPM packages](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download#Linux_.28.rpm.29) starting from version 3.4.